# MySQL delete all rows where id is greater than the given number

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there an Sql query I can run that will enable me to delete all rows where the ID is greater than let's say 10?

Something like this.

I have two columns, ID and Name

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE ID=>10;
```

Comment: What does "->" mean?

Comment: try this DELETE FROM table_name WHERE ID>9;

Comment: It was meant to mean equal or greater than @Strawberry

Comment: Except that you should write `>=` instead of `=>` you have it right there ? :) Check out w3schools page on the DELETE keyword: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_delete.asp

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Your query was nearly perfect ;)

Just try

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE ID>9;
```

You could also use

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE ID>=10;
```

As you already mention.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. Every language is having it in a different way ;)

Comment: Could you do `DELETE FROM table_name WHERE ID >= 10 AND < 15`?

Comment: where id >= 10 and id < 15. For this scenario there is between in most SQL dialects.